# Worksheet.CustomProperites OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, epplus

I need to read [Worksheet.CustomProperies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.customproperties%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Is there any way to read this properties?

I have also tried getting XmlDocument of a workbook and worksheet using

```
 XmlDocument xlDoc =  ws.WorksheetXml;
```

Gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
<dimension ref="A3:K24" />
<sheetViews>
<sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0"><selection activeCell="H14" sqref="H14" /></sheetView>
</sheetViews>
<sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" />
<cols></cols><sheetData />
<pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3" />
<pageSetup orientation="portrait" horizontalDpi="4294967293" verticalDpi="4294967293" r:id="rId2" />
**<customProperties><customPr name="My_CustomProperty" r:id="rId3" /></customProperties>**
</worksheet>
```

I can see a CustomProperty there but not able to see the CustomProperty value. When I go to CustomProperty bin file(Zip the xlsx and extract contents), value is there.

I have uploaded the document [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljph3nnbmddycyn/Users_Template_12_22_Template.xlsx)

Comment: Can you upload the document somewhere?

Comment: Uploaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljph3nnbmddycyn/Users_Template_12_22_Template.xlsx

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with these custom properties but here is one way to extract the contents of the customProperty1.bin file from your sample document using the latest version of EPPlus:

```
using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Users_Template_12_22_Template.xlsx")))
{
    var parts = p.Package.GetParts();
    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        if (part.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.customProperty")
        {
            using (var stream = part.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                stream.Close();

                string customPropertyInfo = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you know the name/location of the customProperty1.bin file you can access it using GetPart() instead of GetParts():

```
var u = new Uri("/xl/customProperty1.bin", UriKind.Relative);
var part = p.Package.GetPart(u);
```

Note you'll need to add a reference to WindowsBase.dll (under the .NET tab in Add Reference) to use Packaging related methods.

Comment: Yes. The solution you have mentioned reads the content of customProperty.bin, but then I am thrown in to the problem of getting CustomProperty name. I need to get CustomPropertyName and relevant Value. Is there any part of XML which has this Name- Value relation i.e.customProperty1.bin belongs to X CustomProeprty name ?

Comment: In your sample file I'm not even sure what value you'd expect for CA_Users_16 but maybe you can get the value somehow if you figure out how the contents are delimited. Here is what I saw from your sample file: Users - Users|16|4|False|True|False|CA_Users_16|20|UserID:0,FirstName:3,RoleID:5,RoleIDs:6,IsActive:8,IsRememberPassword:10

Comment: In my sample, CA_Users_16 is CustomProperty Name. And the '|' separated string is its relevant value. In VSTO on client, I can traverse CustomProperties by Worksheet and Get CustomProperty object whihc gives me name and value. But I am trying to achieve Office Automation on server where I can not use VSTO. The brute force approach would be to get names with what I am doing. And then get all bin data using your method. Make another round for mapping name to values, which won't be a solution.

Comment: The brute force approach isn't ideal but it sounds like it will work. It's possible EPPlus doesn't currently support the custom properties the way you want to use them. One alternative is to look into adding the feature to the source code from the EPPlus site http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets.

Comment: 12 years later I met the same question, may I ask did you resolve this problem? @Cannon